# Is there a $\mathcal{C}^1$ solution for this Cauchy problem?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I have the following Cauchy problem:
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
2u_x+(x+u)u_y=2 \\
u\left(x,\frac{x^2}{2}\right)=x
\end{array}\right.
$$
I want to study whether it has $\mathcal{C}^1$ solutions in a neighborhood of the initial curve
$$\Gamma(s)=\left(s, \frac{s^2}{2},s\right)$$
First I check whether the transversality condition is fulfilled. I have that
$$\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 2s \\
1 & s
\end{vmatrix}=0 \quad \forall s$$
Therefore I check the rank of the extended matrix:
$$\text{rank}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 2s & 2\\
1 & s & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\left\{\begin{array}{lcr}2 & \text{if} & s\neq 1\\ 1 & \text{if} & s=1
\end{array}\right.$$
Therefore if $s\neq1$, the problem has no $\mathcal{C}^1$ solution. However I am having trouble deciding what happens when $s=1$. If I solve the system, for the particular case $s=1$ I get that the solution is $(t+1, 3t^2/2+2t+1/2,2t+1)$. This is not parallel nor the same as my initial curve, so there aren't infinite solutions. What happens here?

Comment: Your mixed problem has a solution $u(x, y) = x$ and it belongs to the class $C^1$. I built this solution using the method of characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Below, consider this as information (or comment) instead of a direct answer.

$$2u_x+(x+u)u_y=2$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{x+u}=\frac{du}{2}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{du}{2}$ :
$$u-x=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{x+(c_1+x)}$ :
$$c_1x+x^2-2y=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ :
$$(u-x)x+x^2-2y=F(u-x)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$\boxed{xu-2y=F(u-x)}$$
Condition :
$$u(x,\frac12 x^2)=x\quad\implies\quad x*x-2(\frac12 x^2)=F(x-x)=F(0)$$
$$F(0)=0$$
They are infinity many functions which are equal to zero when the argument is zero. Thus the PDE with the specified condition has infinity many solutions.

For examples :

With the function $F(X)=0$ we get the solution $u(x,y)=x$ (in agreement with jan's comment).

With F(X)=X we get the solution $u(x,y)=\frac{2y-x}{x-1}$ .

More complicated, with $F(X)=(\exp(X)-1)$ we get the solution $u(x,y)=\frac{2y-1}{x}-W\left(-\frac{1}{x}e^{-(x^2-2y+1)/x} \right)$  involving the $W$ Lambert's function.

But generally one cannot express $u(x,y)$ on explicit form. We have to be satisfied with the implicit equation  $xu-2y=F(u-x)$  with functions $F$ such as $F(0)=0$ for the infinity many solutions.